# Using the This keyword and operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this

I was looking for some advice on how to use the `this` keyword in an overloaded operator. I have tried reading up on it, but it doesn't fully make sense, maybe if someone can explain it somewhat more in depth?

I've also provided the code where my issue is, it is meant to do the addition of two matrices. I have to stick with the `const Matrix&` argument. 
The current errors I'm getting are `no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘const Matrix’ and ‘int’)` for the 4 lines of code that is meant to do the addition.

```
int array1[2][2] = {{5, 7}, {3, 2}}; //makes the 2 dimensional arrays used to represent the matrix 
int array2[2][2] = {{2, 3}, {1, 4}};
Matrix m2(array1);
const Matrix m3(array2);

cout << m2 << " + " << m3 << " = " << m2 + m3 << endl; //here is where the operator + comes into play. (The << operator was overloaded to work with this)
cout << m3 << " + " << m2 << " = " << m3 + m2 << endl << endl;
```

All of the above in found in the main program. Below I have added methods with belong to the .cpp and the some (the needed part) of the class definition.

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& rightOp) const
{
Matrix addedMatrix;

addedMatrix.matrix[0][0] = *this->matrix + rightOp[0][0]; //current issue stands at these for lines
addedMatrix.matrix[0][1] = *this->matrix + rightOp[0][1]; //*this is used to represent the left operand of the expression, which points to the Matrix object that called the method
addedMatrix.matrix[1][0] = *this->matrix + rightOp[1][0];
addedMatrix.matrix[1][1] = *this->matrix + rightOp[1][1];

return addedMatrix;
}


Matrix::Matrix(const int newMatrix[][2]) //constructor where m2 and m3 are passed to
{
for(int row = 0; row < 2; row++)
    for(int col = 0; col < 2; col++)
        matrix[row][col] = newMatrix[row][col];  
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Matrix& newMatrix) //overloaded << operator
{
output << "[[" << newMatrix.matrix[0][0] << ", " << newMatrix.matrix[0][1]         << "], "
           << "[" << newMatrix.matrix[1][0] << ", " << newMatrix.matrix[1][1] << "]]";

return output;
}

class Matrix //Class Defintion for Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(const int[][2]);
    Matrix operator+(const Matrix&) const;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Matrix&);
private:
    int matrix[2][2];
};
```

Comment: Bits and pieces of code are not useful to help you. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very simple and has nothing to do with `this`.

> no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘const Matrix’ and ‘int’)

You haven't defined an `operator[]` for your matrix class and you are trying to invoke one when you write

```
rightOp[0][0]
```

I think what you intended was

```
addedMatrix.matrix[0][0] = this->matrix[0][0] + rightOp.matrix[0][0];
```

and so on. This is identical to writing

```
addedMatrix.matrix[0][0] = matrix[0][0] + rightOp.matrix[0][0];
```

Comment: Do you mean the leading `*` that you had? Because that read "add the whole of this to rightOp.matrix[x][y]" which didn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085956/c-this-and-operator-overloading?rq=1) and see if the solution helps.

Solution pasted here for completeness.

```
Either: this->operator()(i,j) or (*this)(i,j)
```

Comment: So, can I think of it as, it's either gonna be `this->` or `*this`, but not `*this->`? Do the `*` and `->` serve the same job? At least in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

For more help you will need to show the definition of your matrix class, but for starters:

- What the compiler thinks you are trying to do is access an element in a two dimensional array of Matrices, whereas what I think you want is to access a single number within that matrix.
- To use the index operator ([]) in that way you need to overload them in your matrix class, and in this case you can't overload them like that as the index operator only accepts a single integer as it's argument. Any solution involving multiple uses of the index operator is complex in comparison to, say, overloading the () operator so that you can do rightOp( 2, 2 ).
- Your *this->matrix should be trying to access a single value, not the whole matrix.'

EDIT:
After looking at your code, all you're forgetting is that you need to access Matrix.matrix[0][0], not Matrix[0][0]. Remember that you're actually getting your numbers from the array inside the matrix class

Comment: Have added the needed class definition, I only added the needed parts to reduce the amount of space.

Comment: Yeah, I could've sworn I had the earlier and I was still getting issues. But, yeah, it makes sense now. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

`operator+` takes two parameters as input, and returns a new object, not a modified object.  So it does not make sense to implement it as a class member. It is *usually* implemented as a standalone global function instead. `operator+=`, on the other hand, makes more sense as a class method, and `operator+` is *usually* implemented in terms of `operator+`.  For example:

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    int matrix[2][2];

public:
    Matrix(); // initialize matrix to default values
    Matrix(const Matrix &); // copy existing matrix values
    ...

    Matrix& operator+=(const Matrix& rightOp);

    friend Matrix operator+(const Matrix& leftOp, const Matrix& rightOp);
};

Matrix operator+(const Matrix& leftOp, const Matrix& rightOp);
```

```
Matrix operator+(const Matrix& leftOp, const Matrix& rightOp)
{
    Matrix tmp(leftOp);
    tmp += rightOp;
    return tmp;
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator+=(const Matrix& rightOp)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < 2; ++row)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 2; ++col) {
            matrix[row][col] += rightOp.matrix[row][col];  
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

That being said, you *can* implement `operator+` as a class method as well:

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    int matrix[2][2];

public:
    Matrix(); // initialize matrix to default values
    Matrix(const Matrix &); // copy existing matrix values
    ...

    Matrix operator+(const Matrix& rightOp) const;
};
```

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& rightOp) const
{
    Matrix result(*this);
    for(int row = 0; row < 2; ++row)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 2; ++col) {
            result.matrix[row][col] += rightOp.matrix[row][col];  
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& rightOp) const
{
    Matrix result;
    for(int row = 0; row < 2; ++row)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 2; ++col) {
            result.matrix[row][col] = this->matrix[row][col] + rightOp.matrix[row][col];  
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What I was told was that the left expression (represented by `this`) is the left operand.  So, `<< m2 + m3 <<`, m2 will be represented by `this` and then the right operand will be represented by the constant Matrix object. But, with that being said, I do know what you are saying. I have to implement a few more things still, one which is a stand alone function which will used for scalar multiplication (which takes two parameters), both Matrix objects, basically how you described the `operator+`.

Comment: If `operator+` is implemented as a class member, then yes, `this` represents the left-hand operand. As for your scalar multiplication, you can implement `operator*` to handle that.